# Abelian categories with direct sums

Tags: abelian-categories, direct-sum

Does any abelian category admits direct sums?

If not, categories admiting direct sums have a special name?

I'm asking this since I am writing a proof that requires direct sums but I only know that the category is abelian.

Thank you very much for your answer!

Edit. In the tag description is written that indeed they posses finite direct sums.

Comment: what is your definition of abelian category?

Comment: @ Norbert for me an abelian category is one which admits kernels and cokernels and additive, I guess this is essential.

Comment: @Mathuser Are you sure? A *pre* abelian category is an *additive* category which admits kernels and cokernels. Additive categories will have finite coproducts, as you desire.

Comment: If I hvae zero morphisms I do not need additive to define kernels and cokernels. Do I still have direct sums?

Comment: @Henry: Thank you very much! My category is indeed additive by hypothesis. I guess the previous question has negative answer, if it makes any sense.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_morphism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by the definition of an Abelian category, it contains all finite coproducts ("direct sums"). Just look back to your definition of an Abelian product to see all the extra things an Abelian category is assumed to have.

Answer (score 2):

You should clarify what you mean by direct sum. If you mean 'finite direct sum' then this is included in the definition of an abelian category. Arbitrary direct sums don't necessarily exist, like the category of finite abelian groups. An abelian category is called 'cocomplete' if it possesses all direct sums.

Comment: Oog. An abelian category should be called cocomplete if it possesses all colimits. It happens to be the case that for abelian categories this is equivalent to possessing all direct sums (but this is because abelian categories already have coequalizers).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: True, I should have mentioned this.

Answer (score 0):

In an abelian category you have much more than direct sums(=coproducts); you have biproducts, so that the object part is the same for binary products and coproducts and the arrows satisfy some very nice relations..http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biproduct